# What does this answer have that makes it spammy, rude or abusive?

Tags: discussion

A long time ago we had this question:

[City defenses against kaiju attacks?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/127906/21222)

Which, in TL;DR form would read:

> How can civilization fend off against Godzilla sized beasts

I had an answer there which I wanted to reference in another questio  today. But now I found that it was deleted due to being spammy, rude, or abusive (the reason isn't specific). Now it can only be seen by users with 10K+ reputation and mods. Since it was deleted by a moderator, I cannot even vote to undelete. It went like this:

> Any modern society should have no trouble dispatching kaijus.
>
> For the biological reasons:
>
> [Here I inserted an image with the biological explanation for why gigantic lizards would be mostly harmless]
>
> For the mechanical reasons,.see [this answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/106434/21222).

The image I used was a comic found in [this link](http://smbc-comics.com/comic/gojirasaurus):

[image: A harmless comic]

---

I am not trying to sell nor promote SMBC and I don't consider myself a spammer. I understand some people get offended very easily but I don't see any malice nor *ad hominem* there, nor can I imagine someone feeling attacked by the post - so if I have been rude I apologize but I haven't realized how I came across like that. Finally, I don't see what kind of abuse could be perceived in it.

I really want to be fair and nice. An explanation instead of a boilerplate set of possible reasons would be helpful.

Comment: In fairness its a great comic...

Comment: I've *wondered* where that answer went - I was looking for it a while back (couldn't remember which comics was involved, just that it an awesome counter to a scientifically plausible kaiju) - thought I've just remembered wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Disclaimer: I am not the moderator who removed the post. I see a user flagged it as rude and a moderator acknowledged that flag**

The major issue I have with answers having their core in an image (or a strip like in this case) is that they intrinsically rule out being universally understood.

Just to give you an example, a visually impaired user, who has to use screen reading for accessing the content of their screen, would have been listening to the following speech (in *italics* the text replacing the image, that you took care inserting, at least):

> Any modern society should have no trouble dispatching kaijus.
>
> For the biological:
>
> *Science ruins all the fun*
>
> For the mechanical, see this answer

Now, does that compare to actually reading the strip? They are like day and night!

The way I see it, the answer could be greatly improved by adding a written explanation, and using the strip as punch line. Yes, it would lose part of the impact becoming lengthy, but remember that our primary goal should be to give thorough explanations on how to solve problems, not to be ZIP ZAP BANG.

Comment: Adding the speech bubbles as cited text and linking to Wikipedia / explaining a few things *after* the comic would be enough to make the answer a real answer and at the same time keep it short for those who can read the comic and know the terms used there.

Comment: For what it is worth, I edited the transcript into the image. I still can't vote to undelete it though.

Comment: I would suggest fleshing it out a bit beyond the comic.

Answer (score 6):

It would appear that - rather to my surprise - that it was I who deleted that post.

I must say,  having looked at it just now, I can't see why I might have agreed that it was offensive.  I also don't remember having deleted it, and it's an unusual enough post that it would have stuck in my mind.

My only explanation is that I do most of my moderation on my phone's browser, and on occasion, the screen lock I set to prevent inadvertent input when I put my phone in my pocket doesn't work,  and when that happens, I can get a *lot* of spurious input. It is entirely possible that on such an occasion, that spurious input may have caused the deletion of this answer, without my noticing.

So, I offer my apologies for this error.  I have undeleted the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I do a lot of work by cell phone as well, and I know how that feels :)

Comment: I've seen the damndest things on my screen after a lock failure... on one occasion, it had apparently tried to buy a whole lot of skimpy women's beachwear and ship it to Afghanistan... fortunately I don't let my phone remember any financial passwords, so it couldn't finalise the transaction... but the gods only know what else it might have done beforehand...